# Trying to absolute center ul (vertical and horizontal) in nav

Tags: html, css

... with the help of this tutorial at > [coding.smashingmagazine.com/..](http://goo.gl/LLXTKb)

```
nav {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #333;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 100%;
}
```

I can't get it right. Look at my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9N2hW/).

Thanks for any help.

An [image](http://www.redfoxwebdesign.nl/fora/jsfiddle.net:9N2hW%3a.png) ... chrome/macos x 10.8.x > is the ul v/h centered?

Comment: It actually does what it should, the `ul` is centered in `nav`. What else would you like to see?

Comment: What browser support do you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get rid of the absolute positioning, if you're willing to have a fixed height to your nav container, you can just use line height, **[like so](http://jsfiddle.net/GYatesIII/RQkWe/3/)**:

```
nav {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 200px; /* This must be defined and match the line-height below */
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding: 0;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 200px; /* This must match the nav height defined above */
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also to remind me of `white-space:nowrap`. Nevertheless I tried to fiddle with the code of the  smashing article ... but it doesn't work either ... :/

Comment: BTW ... getting the baseline of the li's exact in the middle van the nav I increased the height of the nav with the font-size of the li. But that doesn't quite work if you make the height('s) small ... let's say 70px. Maybe you have some thoughts how to tackle this one?

Comment: I don't know why but give the nav font-size: 100% and a small height does the job too. Still remains the centered baseline (li's) question ...

Comment: And with line-height: 1 for the nav [everything](http://jsfiddle.net/Mq2DQ/3/) is fine ... :) ... only I don't know why ... presumably the code overrides some defaults ... !?

Comment: I got rid of the `font-size` and `line-height` declaration for the `nav` element and amended the `line-height` on the `li` to match the `nav` height, here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GYatesIII/Mq2DQ/4/)**, does this not do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This could be much more easily accomplished with the following CSS. No need for absolute on the UL. See http://jsfiddle.net/9N2hW/2/

```
nav {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #333;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 200px;
}
```